# Order of execution of controller method calls during rerender

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, rerender

Let's say we have an `apex:commandButton`, with `immediate="false"`, and no `apex:actionSupport`. It's just a standard `apex:commandButton` inside an `apex:form`.

Additionally, suppose it has a `reRender` attribute which rerenders some form elements.

This page leaves out an important detail:

[Order of Execution for Visualforce Page Postback Requests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_postback_request.htm)

Namely, when the various form elements are rerendered, you may imagine that some of them will call methods on the controller. For example, there may be some methods called to retrieve Boolean values to control the `"rendered"` attribute of certain elements. Additionally, elements such as `apex:selectOptions` may call methods on the controller to retrieve `List<T>` for their `"value"` attribute.

Is there any defined order for these method calls, or is it non-deterministic?

Here is one of my use cases where this is important. I have an `apex:selectOptions` which calls a controller action in its `"value"` attribute. Let's call this action `"getOptions()"`. This must be run at postback time, as its contents are sensitive to certain controller member variables that are assigned by input elements during the postback. Also, I have some sections on the page that either render, or do not, depending upon whether `"getOptions()"` contains any data.

It would be ideal not to have to make 2 SOQL queries, one for the List and the other to retrieve a `COUNT()` aggregate, using the same predicate, but I can't see another option, since `getOptions()` may not have been called by the time the other element needs to know how many options were returned. It seems I need another method, `getOptionCount()` in order to be guaranteed to get the count.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't depend on the order of setters or getters. You should avoid doing this at all cost. In fact, you can't even guarantee that your setters or getters will be called only once per transaction, so your "two queries" might very well become four or six (or more!), depending on page structure.

If you must use this design, then opt for "lazy initialization", like so:

```
transient SObject[] records { get; set; }

void loadRecords() {
    if(records == null) {
        records = [select ... from ... where ...];
    }
}
public SObject[] getOptions() {
    loadRecords();
    // Do something with records
    return someArray;
}
public Integer getOptionsCount() {
    loadRecords();
    return records.size();
}
```

This makes sure your query is ran only once per transaction without regards to how many times your getters might be called. If view state size unimportant, you can simply assign the value during your action methods whenever they need to be updated. The bulk of any rendering you do should be within constructors or action methods, not getters or setters.

Comment: Thanks. I figured, based on absence of a definitive statement to the contrary, that there was no guarantee of order or number of executions. I like the tactic of delegating to loadRecords(), however I have cases where getOptionCount() may be called independently (minor rerender), and it will be more efficient to have a separate SOQL call which merely uses the COUNT() aggregate instead of mapping the entire dataset into memory via an SObject[] array or List<SObject>.

Comment: As an aside, for other readers, getOptionCount() is a better MVC pattern than other things  I have seen, such as public void showThisSection{}, etc., as those patterns are putting view logic in the controller.

Comment: By the way, why editorialize about getters/setters, as my post did not reference getters/setters, and specifically referenced method calls? Just curious.

Comment: @PittsburghDBA `getX` and `setX` methods are also getters and setters, simply in a different form. The inline/default model provides a backing variable automatically and thus produces a different syntax from the function model, but this difference in syntax only surfaces in Apex Code-- as far as Visualforce is concerned, either model of getters and setters are acceptable.

Comment: OK, so that's just platform voodoo, or sytactic sugar. For example, I named that getOptionCount() because I'm a long-time developer "out in the world". A real property accessor (AKA "gettor") would look like this: public Integer optionCount{ get { return this.optionCount; } }

Comment: That is how you write property accessors. Otherwise, it's just the SFDC platform using reflection to find your "get" method. Taking advantage of automatic backing variables added by the compiler such as: public Integer optionCount {get; set;} is completely different.

Comment: In other words, just because a method begins with "get" doesn't make it a "gettor" in programming terms. It just so happens that SFDC, in the absence of a legitimate accessor/getter, will use reflection to fall back and find a public method with the "get" prefix. This is in no way the same as properties.

Comment: You can prove this by making a real property such as public Integer optionCount { get { return 1; } }    With this syntax, you can bind to a value attribute in Visualforce, and there is no need for "get" prefix in your Apex. Properties and methods serve different purposes. Typically a property accessor would not have side effects, hit a database, etc, whereas a method is the appropriate tactic for those use cases.

Comment: @PittsburghDBA In salesforce.com terminology, we don't have "accessors" or "mutators". They are always referred to as "getters" and "setters." In the rare cases where those words appear in the manual, they always appear next to the word "getter" or "setter" (or the plural, of course). Don't believe me? See [Defining Getter Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_controller_getter_methods.htm). I realize this isn't true in Java, but Apex Code isn't Java.

Comment: @PittsburghDBA In fact, going one step further, look at the Visualforce Lifecycle information, they refer to two distinct steps, one for calling setters before the action method, and one for calling the getters after the action method. The documentation makes no distinction between getX/setX methods and { get; set; } methods-- they can be called in any arbitrary order within the appropriate step, and so are considered interchangeable.

Comment: At this point, we have moved into pedantry, which is unfortunate. I wanted to point out that I was not so concerned with "getters and setters" (property accessors), but the order of method calls in general, which is non-deterministic. What I wanted was a reference in Salesforce's spotty documentation, that explicitly explained this. In the meantime, I had developed the architecture, conservatively. The reason I wrote my comments about "getters and setters" is because some people are coming here from other platforms, where those terms means something very specific, and narrow.

Comment: Your comment about the absence of mutators and accessors is funny, in light of this contradictory post that you wrote about this exact subject. https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000092DMIAY

Comment: @PittsburghDBA By the way: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_lifecycle_example.htm (might) cover what you're looking for. And yes, I did call them mutators and accessors, because that's what they *are* (a rose by any other name...), but the documentation, for whatever reason, steers away from those terms. The order of execution between what we know to be accessors/getters and mutators/setters are mixed and indeterminate in order, which is what you're trying to get to.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I can see that you are a very helpful and experienced member of the community. I think it's interesting that the platform supports "looking around", presumably with reflection, for an action attribute's method. It seems it looks for a property first, and then a method prefixed with "get". I don't understand why they didn't just make you put the actual method name. Odd.